# Listar datos en flutter con firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

Estoy iniciando en flutter y en mi aplicación busco mostrar una card para cada key que se encuentre en firebase

es decir que el key sea el texto titulo y el subtitulo el valor de la key,
se me ocurrio crear una listview para mostrar los datos

para ello trate de hacer lo siguiente pero no muestra ningun dato:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'nuevo.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
   home: MyHomePage(),
  ));
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  List <Post> list=new List();

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text("Data"),
    ),
    body: new Container(
      child:new Center(
        child: new ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (BuildContext context ,int index){
          return new Card(
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text(list[index].title),
                new Text(list[index].content)
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
        itemCount: list==null?0:list.length,
        ),
      )
    )
 );
 }
}
```

nuevo.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Post {
  String title;
  String content;
  Post(this.title,this.content);

  Post.fromJson(var value){
    this.title = value['title'];
    this.content = value['content'];
  }

}
```

Si me pudieran apoyar con documentacion o un tutorial completo sobre firebase con flutter tambiense los agradeceria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que tu colección de Firestore sea algo asi:

```
{
'title': 'title', 
'content': 'content'
}
```

En si, consigues todos los datos de Firebase con: `Firestore.instance.collection('{your_collection_name}').snapshots()`, y podrías usar `StreamBuilder` conseguir conseguir todos los datos de tu colección.

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('{your_collection_name}').snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return new Card(
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Text(snapshot.data.documents[index].title),
              new Text(snapshot.data.documents[index].content)
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    );
  }
)
```

#### Explicación

El atributo `stream` obtendrá todos los datos que `Firestore.instance.collection('{your_collection_name}').snapshots()` devuelva, en este caso es una petición para conseguir todos los datos de la colección "{your_collection_name}", asegurate de cambiar el argumento que le  pasas a `collection` a el nombre de tu colección.

En el atributo `builder` tenemos una función que toma un `BuildContext` y un `AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>`. Adentro de la función verificamos que `snapshot` tenga algún dato con `if (!snapshot.hasData)`, si no tiene datos, retornamos un `CircularProgressIndicator` para que parezca que esta cargando. En el caso de que snapshot tenga algún dato, llamamos el `ListView` que tu usaste, nada mas que envés de usar `list` usamos `snapshot.data.documents` que es una lista con todos los datos de tu colección.

Como podrás ver, no utilice la clase `List`. Se me hace mas fácil así, aunque usar la clase podría mejorar la facilidad de leer tu código. Podrías partir de esta información para utilizar tu clase `List` o dejarlo así como te dejo en la sección de **Código**.

#### Código

**main.dart**

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'nuevo.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
   home: MyHomePage(),
  ));
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  List <Post> list=new List();

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text("Data"),
    ),
    body: new Container(
      child:new Center(
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('{your_collection_name}').snapshots(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return new Card(
                  child: new Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Text(snapshot.data.documents[index].title),
                      new Text(snapshot.data.documents[index].content)
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }
            );
          }
        )
      )
    )
  );
 }
}
```

#### Recomendaciones de tutoriales

- **Yo use este tutorial cuando buscaba como realizar operaciones CRUD a Firebase: [Using Cloud Firestore as a Realtime Datastore for CRUD with Dart's Flutter Framework](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OJ_u34bD_q8), Esta en ingles, no se si te sirva.**